# Size of data type Geography(Point, 4326) in PostGIS?

Tags: size, postgis, point, geography

Its constructor takes a POINT and a SRID. Since POINT is two doubles (8 bytes each), SRID is an integer (4 bytes), can one assume that the full structure takes 8*2+4=20 bytes of storage space?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I can tell you that it is not so easy, as to apply a simple calculation. The database stores not only the data but indices to that data. You can even have multiple types of index (There are multiple database-index types (unique, multicolumn, etc.) and for geographic data you have a GIST-index (generalized search tree))

Comment: srid is not stored for every row, is a characteristic of  the column. A crude estimation will be  `no_rows * 2 * 8  + 4`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [ST_Mem_Size](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Mem_Size.html). This gives you the size of toast tables, as well, so is more suitable than pg_total_relation_size and other built in Postgres functions, which do not -- although this only applies to larger geometries. Returning to your question, for a point,

```
SELECT ST_Mem_Size(ST_MakePoint(0, 0));
```

returns 32 bytes, which is 4 doubles (rather than the 2 you would expect). The reason for this is that there is additional meta-data, such as the endianness to store.

Add in the SRID, with,

```
SELECT ST_Mem_Size(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 4326));
```

returns 32 bytes.

Now, a Linestring, with two points,

```
SELECT ST_Mem_Size(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)'), 4326));
```

returns 48 bytes, which is now only 16 bytes, that is 2 doubles, larger than the Point, as you would expect.

Now, if you buffer this point,

```
SELECT ST_Mem_Size(ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 10), 4326));
```

you get 568 bytes, which due to the fact that there are 8 points by default per quarter circle segment, plus a repeated start point at the end, which you can check with,

```
SELECT ST_NPoints(ST_SetSRID(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 10), 4326));
```

gives you 33*16 = 528, with the other 40 bytes coming from the SRID, endianness, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please comment on SRID, is it stored for every record or for the whole column?

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID:
In spatially enabled databases [...], SRIDs are used to uniquely identify the coordinate systems used to define columns of spatial data or individual spatial objects in a spatial column (depending on the spatial implementation)."

Comment: Yes, so the SRID is only included once per geometry record, which is why when you go from a Point to a LineString with two points, both with the SRID set, the size only increases by 16 bytes, as the SRID has already been recorded.

Comment: I understand that adding more points to a LineString doesn't add more SRIDs. But we can have multiple LineString objects, one per record, and then I still wonder whether or not each record contains its own SRID.

Comment: Yes, each record will still contain its own SRID, because you can mix geometries with different SRIDs in the same column, though it is not, in my opinion, a good idea.